# Density/probability function of discrete and continuous random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I was wondering how does the rules of probability apply if we have a **discrete** random variable $Y$ and a **continuous** random variable $X$.

What would $P(Y=y,X=x)$ be equal to? Is joint **probability** defined or is it joint **density function**? (note: I denote probability as $P$ and density functions with $f$)

Is it correct to write:

$$P(Y=y|X=x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(y,x)}{f_X(x)}$$

or should I write:

$$f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(y,x)}{f_X(x)}$$

How does the continuous random variable affect the joint properties of the two random variables? Is it correct to say that:

> If the random variables are both discrete, then the we can state their
>   relationships with the  probability $P$-function, but if either one or
>   both of them are continuous then we have to describe the probabilistic
>   relationship using density functions $f$.

For example, if I denote random variable $Z$ as $Z = (X,Y)$ (vector), then is the space where $Z$ is defined in continuous or discrete?

Hope my question is clear enough :) In summary: I'm just trying to figure out how does the mixing of discerete and continuous random variables affect the probability space :)

Thnx for any help!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/608906/6179