# A specific question in conditional expectation with mixed discrete and continuous random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

In my probability class I have just met this seemingly difficult question:

> Let $ \{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}, \{Z_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ be two i.i.d sequences of random variables such that we know $  X_n \sim \mathcal{N} (0,\sigma ^2) $ and $  Z_n \sim \mathcal{N} (0,1) $ and we define a new sequence of random variables like so:
>   $ Y_n = X_N-X_n+Z_n $ where $ N \sim POIS(\Lambda) $ statistically independent from $ X_n,Z_n $. The question has three parts:
>
> 1. We are asked to show that $ X_N,N $ are statistically independent. Done I did this
> 2. We are asked to find the conditional probability $ q_{m,n} = P\{ N=m | Y_n=y \}  $ (for fixed deterministic m,n) where we are asked to distinguish between whether or not $ m=n $. I am stuck here as there is a hybrid of a discrete and a continuous random variable.
> 3. We are to asked to find the conditional expectation $ E[X_n | Y_n] $ (for fixed deterministic n) and we are asked to express the result in terms of $ q_{m,n}. Really stuck here, no idea.

I realize this might seem like a tough question but I am still a novice in probability theory and on the last two parts where I got stuck I cannot seem to find a solution and also the third part relies on the second where I am stuck so they are connected. I truly need and appreciate the help. Thanks all.

Comment: Well $X_N$ is actually a continuous random variable; it is just that the index is random. Also are we talking random sequences or random variables or random vectors? I am somewhat confused about the setup of the problem.

Comment: @WilliamKrinsman : Where exactly is your confusion?

Comment: Well the poisson distribution is distributed on the natural numbers -- so N can be any natural number. Thus $X_N$ doesn't make sense unless $X_n$ is defined for all natural numbers n. But you mention random vectors (a finite, not infinite number of indices), not random sequence (countable number of indices).

Comment: @WilliamKrinsman : sorry I meant infinite random vectors

Comment: Also the distributions you gave seem to be for one-dimensional RVs, not random vectors (which have mean vectors and covariance matrices), although you might just be using compact notation.

Comment: @WilliamKrinsman : Thanks I just meant sequences of random variables sorry for the confusion

Comment: I tried to answer 2., but for 3. I don't understand what you are asking at all. It seems like there are probably some points where lowercase n is supposed to be replaced by uppercase N, but I can't tell, and hence can't answer your question.

Comment: I assume you have already solved the problem by now, but if not, one of the links I found in answering this other question might be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1784483/327486

Comment: In particular, I would encourage you to look at this answer, since it is written by one of the best probability experts on Math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596816/a-basic-doubt-on-joint-distribution/608906#608906

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. Assuming that the P here means conditional density and not conditional probability (which would be the only definition that makes sense, since Y=y with probability 0), we have $P(N=m|Y=y)=\frac{P(N=m \cap Y=y)}{f_Y(y)}=\frac{P(N=m)f_Y(y)}{ f_Y (y)}=P(N=m)$ (since by part 1 N and $X_N$ are independent, and obviously N is independent of the other remaining terms of $Y_n$). Hence the conditional density doesn't vary from that of the Poisson distribution (we can rewrite its probability mass function as a probability density which is a step function).
3. $X_n = X_N + Z_n - Y_n \implies E[X_n|Y_n]=E[X_N + Z_n -Y_n|Y_n] = E[X_N|Y_n] + E[Z_n|Y_n]-E[Y_n|Y_n] = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} q_{n,m} + E[Z_n|Y_n] + Y_n$ because of the independence relations from part 1. I'm not sure how to proceed further at the moment.

Comment: I might be able to give a more correct answer if you could give me the location/source of the question, so as to understand the context better. Doesn't always help, but it does sometimes.

Comment: As it stands now, don't know what to do, to be honest. @Did